# Lag in HTML5 / Canvas toDataURL

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a webpage where you can select images (and eventually manipulate and save them back to your computer).  My manipulation widget actually needs the files to be jpegs or pngs (like a normal img).

So far I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xg3VN/3/

```
function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    $('body').append($('<img>').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL()));

}
```

There's a lag--you select a file and displays it, but I'd like it to append an image with source from "toDataURL" to the end of the page.

Right now, there's a lag of one cycle. The first image is only appended when the second is uploaded.

I think the answer involves callbacks, but I'm lost here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the last part of that method inside the load handler:

```
function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var domImg = new Image();          // create a new image object
            domImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();   // set canvas URL as source
            $('body').append(domImg);          // append to body
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xg3VN/4/)**

You can append right away as the DOM and element will be updated when ready. Note that if you need to use the image for something right after creating the image you would need another onload handler:

```
var domImg = new Image();          // create a new image object
domImg.onload = nextStep;          // go to this function after loaded
domImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();   // set canvas URL as source
$('body').append(domImg);          // append to body
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to create the dataURL inside the onload function:**

Here's an example that creates both an img element and a canvas element using FileReader:

```
function handleFiles(files) {

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      var imageType = /image.*/;

      if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
        continue;
      }

      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.classList.add("obj");
      img.file = file;

      // testing...adds the new img element to a div with id="preview"

      preview.appendChild(img);

      var reader=new FileReader();
      reader.onload=(function(aImg){
          return function(e) {
              aImg.onload=function(){
                  var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
                  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
                  canvas.width=aImg.width;
                  canvas.height=aImg.height;
                  ctx.drawImage(aImg,0,0);

                  // testing...adds the temp canvas to the body
                  // if you need canvas.toDataURL, you can also do that now

                  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
              }
              // e.target.result is a dataURL for the image
              aImg.src = e.target.result;
          }; 
      })(img);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    } // end for

} // end handleFiles
```

**Full code example: drag-drop image from desktop and create both img & canvas elements**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    #dropzone{border:1px solid blue; width:300px;height:300px;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // dropzone event handlers
    var dropzone;
    dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");
    dropzone.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
    dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
    dropzone.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

    //
    function dragenter(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    //

    function dragover(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    //
    function drop(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();

      var dt = e.dataTransfer;
      var files = dt.files;

      handleFiles(files);
    }

    // create img and/or canvas elements from dropped image files

    function handleFiles(files) {

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var file = files[i];
          var imageType = /image.*/;

          if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
          }

          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.classList.add("obj");
          img.file = file;
          preview.appendChild(img);

          var reader=new FileReader();
          reader.onload=(function(aImg){
              return function(e) {
                  aImg.onload=function(){
                      var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
                      var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
                      canvas.width=aImg.width;
                      canvas.height=aImg.height;
                      ctx.drawImage(aImg,0,0);
                      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                  }
                  // e.target.result is a dataURL for the image
                  aImg.src = e.target.result;
              }; 
          })(img);
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        } // end for

    } // end handleFiles

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Drag an image from desktop to blue dropzone.</h4>
    <div id="dropzone"></div>
    <div id="preview"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example--I'm still trying to get my head around a lot of this stuff.